# Neomutt - Can't display Swedish characters

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, locale, mutt, unicode

I have an issue regarding `neomutt` not displaying the Swedish characters `å, ä and ö`.

When typing `locale` in the terminal I get:

```
LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_SE.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

When viewing the subject text in neomutt I get an question mark whenever it should be a character `å, ä or ö`. When I open an email I get `\366` instead of `ö`, `\345` instead of `å` and `\344` instead of `ä`.

I'm using `5.0.7-arch1-1-ARCH`.

Comment: what is the output of `locale charmap` ?

Comment: octal 366 is the iso8859-1 encoding of `ö`, not the UTF-8 encoding. Chances are those emails are not properly formatted. If you press `h` within `neomutt` when viewing that email, do you see a `Content-Type` header? What does it say for the charset?

Comment: @RadovanGarabík I get `UTF-8`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, I do and it says: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"`

Comment: Finally found the solution. My initial setting of `LC_COLLATE=sv_SE.UTF-8` didn't work as it should've, I had to set it to `sv_SE.utf8`. So now the characters in the email body text works but I still can't see the correct characters in the subject text when viewing all the emails.

Comment: Also found the solution to the issue with my subject text. I tried sending myself a email with `åäö` and it showed up in my subject text. I found it weird because all my other mail didn't show those characters in it's subject text. I therefore tried refreshing my cache to see if it was because they were stored differently, which it did. Everything seems to be working now!

Comment: @RamoMislimi You should submit you findings and solution as an answer (and later accept that answer). Doing so would benefit people with the same issue as you. You should also mention (in the question) what Unix you are using as locale names may differ between Unices.

Comment: @Kusalananda Sounds reasonable. I've now added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the incorrect locale settings. Initially when I did set up my locales I enteret the same locale name that was found in `/etc/locale.gen`, which was `sv_SE.UTF-8`.

When you uncomment the locale of your choice in `/etc/locale.gen` you have to run `locale-gen` which is a program that reads `locale.gen` and generates localisation files. The available ones can now be found by running `locale -a` in the terminal.

When I ran `locale -a` I noticed that the `sv_SE.UTF-8` wasn't an option, but `sv_SE.utf8` was. What I then had to do was change my locale configurations in `/etc/locale.conf` and make sure that `LC_COLLATE` was set to `sv_SE.utf8` instead of `sv_SE.UTF-8`. After doing this the new settings will be applied after reboot of the machine. You can also change the locale temporarily by running `export LC_COLLATE=sv_SE.utf8` and then try to run neomutt to confirm that the correct characters are shown.

Efter you've rebooted your machine you can run `locale` to check if the locales has been changed.

Another solution is to add `export LC_*=sv_SE.utf8` in your profile file that is being executed whenever you open a new terminal window.